# soul package with Latex delimiter

Tags: beamer, highlighting, delimiters, soul

I would like to ask that how can we use Latex delimiter `\(\)` instead of `$…$` inside parameter of `\hl{}` highlight from soul package?

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{soul,xcolor}
\sethlcolor{yellow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\let\HL\hl
\renewcommand\hl{%
  \let\set@color\beamerorig@set@color
  \let\reset@color\beamerorig@reset@color
  \HL}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hl{This is a function $f^{3}$.} % this is okay

% \hl{This is a function \(f^{3}\).} % but this is not
\end{document}
```

Comment: as the documentation says  "Note that the LATEX equivalent `\(...\)` does not work."